How do i parse the query response I get from aws neptune(using gremlin for query)
I'm working on a Node.js application that interacts with an AWS Neptune graph database using the Gremlin-JavaScript client. My goal is to query the graph for specific vertices based on their labels and IDs and then send this data to my client in a JSON format. However, the response format I receive from my Gremlin queries includes Map objects and EnumValue instances, which I'm finding challenging to serialize directly into JSON.
The code which runs the query:
`async function searchVertices(identityTypeId, identityId) {
    let functionName = 'Search Vertices';
    try {
        let result = await g.V().hasLabel(identityTypeId).has('id', identityId).as('V')
            .union(__.select('V').valueMap(true), __.select('V').in_().group()
                .by(__.label())
                .by(__.valueMap(true).unfold().fold()))
            .toList();

        // console.log('result', JSON.stringify(result));
        console.log(`[INFO][${functionName}] searched related platform nodes of given identity succesfully.`);
        return {
            status: true,
            result: JSON.stringify(result)
        };
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(`[ERROR][${functionName}] error in searching related platform nodes of given identity.`, error);
        return {
            status: false,
            error: error
        };
    }
}`

for connecting to aws neptune:

`const gremlin = require('gremlin');
const DriverRemoteConnection = gremlin.driver.DriverRemoteConnection;
const Graph = gremlin.structure.Graph;
const __ = gremlin.process.statics;

const dc = new DriverRemoteConnection('wss://xxxxx:8182/gremlin', {});
const graph = new Graph();
const g = graph.traversal().withRemote(dc);

module.exports = {
    graph,
    g,
    __
};`

The Issue
When running a Gremlin query from my JavaScript application, the response I receive is structured as follows (simplified for brevity):

`[
    Map(3) {
      [EnumValue] => '58c756f7-9b31-0ca2-a6c6-bdb012d89b27',
      [EnumValue] => '8c732fc7-5e19-4497-9a9d-b0e8576a8214',
      'id' => [Array]
    },
    Map(1) { 'flowstax' => [Array] }
  ]`


How can I effectively parse the Gremlin query response into a normal JSON object that's easily serializable and can be sent to my client? I'm looking for a general approach or utility function that can handle Map objects and EnumValue keys conversion.
`async function searchVertices(identityTypeId, identityId) {
const functionName = 'Search Vertices';
try {
const result = await g.V().hasLabel(identityTypeId).has('id', identityId).as('V')
.union(
.select('V').valueMap(true),
_.select('V').in().group()
.by(.label())
.by(__.valueMap(true).unfold().fold())
)
.toList();
    console.log(`[INFO][${functionName}] Search completed successfully.`);
    return { status: true, result: JSON.stringify(result) }; // Issue here
} catch (error) {
    console.error(`[ERROR][${functionName}] Error occurred:`, error);
    return { status: false, error };
}

}`

Perhaps try falling back to using GraphSONV2 as the serializer.  This post describes how to do that when creating your DriverRemoteConnection: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61260270/using-aws-appsync-with-aws-neptune/61261006#61261006
